# When to use "new" keyword android API

Tags: java, android

I am new to programming and trying to understand why sometimes it appears that objects are instantiated without a "new" keyword. For instance the basic tutorial app from google's android tutorial:

In the ["Build an Intent"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#BuildIntent) example, an `Intent` is created using the `new` keyword:

```
/** Called when the user taps the Send button */
public void sendMessage(View view) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, DisplayMessageActivity.class);
    EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
...
}
```

But later in ["Display the Message"](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html#DisplayMessage), they make an `Intent` object this way if I am understanding correctly:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_message);

    // Get the Intent that started this activity and extract the string
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    ...
}
```

And use the getIntent() method. Also, where is getIntent() method defined? It is a method from the Intent class?

Also on the previous section (https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity.html) they make a new editText but I still don't understand why the "new" keyword isn't used:

```
EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: That's a function from your base class; you aren't directly instantiating an object.  Inside that function, it might use `new` or return something else.  Learn the basics of Java classes.

Comment: You can just to navigate to these methods implementation. But the rough idea (just for you to get it fast) of, eg, getIntent() method, is just to check if here is an intent that was attached for this activity, and findViewById method is just trying to seek an **existing** object in the context (as an abstract term, not android's Context class) of this activity's of fragment's content view. the `new` keyword is used to allocate memory for a new object to instantiate and configure. But what really will help you get it is a nice java core tutorial. Oracle's java newbies tutorial would be just ok.

Answer (score 1):

Good to learn that you want to start learning code.. I have added the solutions to your two questions, best is to just keep going and then everything will start to look logical, step by step.. The beginning is the hardest..

Intent intent = getIntent();

This instantiates an Intent object, the value comes from the function getIntent().. In the following link you can find that it is a method from the class Activity and returns the intent that started this activity.

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html

EditText editText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editText);

This is a referral to a field "editText", defined in your Layout File. 
You refer to the ressource in the layout.. 
Better and clear is to use another naming..

EditText "how you want to name the field" = (EditText) findViewById (R.id."name of the field in the layout")

As suggested below, try to take some basic classes online, watch some tutorials and hang in there!

Good luck!

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help. Here is my question now:

So when I call a function that returns an object data type and I assign it to a variable of that data type, I do not use the new keyword because I am not allocating memory for a new object instance, but rather am assigning an object to a new variable? I think I don't quite understand.

I believe I understand the rest. When you say "how you want to name the field" you are talking about how you will name in in the java class code. While "name of the field..." refers to the id in the xml resource file. Correct?

thanks!

Comment: When you use the new keyword, you instantiate an object of a certain class. This is a function that is declared elsewhere and "performs a certain task".. When you call that function it performs the task it is programmed to do and returns a value. That value is then given to the variable. Try to take some Basics Android/ Java tutorials on Youtube.. Best advice I can give you.. If you like my answer you can "upvote" it..

Comment: Ok, thanks! Yes, I upvoted it but my account is brand new so it doesn't show publicly :)